# AvPlayer with distortion

Tags: ios, core-animation, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Is there a way to have an (one single) AVPlayerLayer cover the area as shown in the image below?
The player should cover both the white and red area with the appropriate perspective.

[image]

Comment: Cover which area? The white section, the red section, the black background, or a single layer covering both the white and red sections with a bend in the middle?

Comment: Updated - should cover the white and red areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can't do this with one layer with an affine transform. Maybe with Core Image, but I don't know what filter(s) you'd use and they'd probably be really expensive anyway.

What you might be able to do is use multiple AVPlayerLayers, each playing the same item, with their 3D transforms set so that they intersect at the fold point. The left side of the right layer would be behind the left layer, and the right side of the left layer would be behind the right layer.

- You'd probably want to have both player layers inside an AVSynchronizedLayer to keep them playing to the same clock.
- I don't know whether you'll need two AVPlayers. At any rate, it's easy enough to get the `playerItem` from one and create a second AVPlayer around it.

As you can guess, I haven't done this, so caveat implementor. Hopefully it'll set you in the right direction.

Comment: I considered this but was unaware of AVSynchronizedLayer. Will look into that one and upvote if it works :-)

Comment: playerItem may only be used in one player - "AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

Comment: As of iOS6 you can use multiple AVPlayerLayers for a single AVPlayer -  as simple as that :-)